# php class private property access outside class

Tags: php, class, oop

```
class A
{
   private $x=100;
   private $y=200;

}
$a=new A();

$x=(array) $a;

foreach($x as $key=>$val)
{
  echo $x[$key];
}
```

I have issue with the `private` variable of `Class A`.

Class A private variable access outside the class when I do typecasting object to array. It should not be access outside the class. But above example I can access private variable of class A.

Here is the result

```
100200
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Reflections can do that too. Just saying...

Comment: `access` means you can manipulate it in the class, but you cant do this on private/proteced Members.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to want to block that?

Comment: Have a read of [this interesting article](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/fast-php-object-to-array-conversion/)

Comment: Simple dont cast class to an array. You can `foreach` over class properties, but when you do that you dont get to see the private properties

Comment: The purpose or private members is not privacy, but rather to ensure the class functions properly and no outside intervention can break intended behaviour. Since the manipulation can only occur on an array and not on class objects themselves then the principle is not violated.

Comment: What is the purpose of this question? There are a metric ton of ways in which "private" properties can be accessed. If you're concerned about "security", you're betting on the wrong horse. If you have another motive, spell it out, please.

Comment: @FirstOne What? Then show me how you will prevent `access`  to anything? `access` on a class member means `$obj->Membername`, all other stuff is php general stuff and has nothing to do with `access a private class member` ;)

Comment: Well I'm with the OP in that it is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @apokryfos Of course, there's always explicit ways to *really* break privacy, for instance using the Reflection API. Access modifiers are more of a sign post with a slap on the wrist denoting *intention* to fellow programmers, it doesn't "protect" anything from anything under all circumstances.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, you are right. But when I do typecasting with array then it should not be access private variable. As per my knowledge private variable access should inside class only. We can not access this outside class.

Comment: Did you read @MarkBaker suggested article?

Comment: @Nikunj K. Did you now `serialize()` ?

Comment: The only guarantee that visibility modifiers provide is that *member access on the instance* will be restricted, i.e. when you do `$obj->member`. And even that is somewhat half-hearted (*cough* Reflection *cough*). Nobody ever said that the *values* will under no circumstances be accessible outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not accessing private members there. All you've got is an array holding the state of the object. Encapsulation is preserved, you're not allowed private member manipulation outside the class blocks.

Now you're allowed to bend over backwards and get the object state which you can use to do whatever, but that's just a poorly written client.

There's only so much a language can do, you should be free to write good/bad code in any language.

Answer (score 4):

First of all I'll start with, the purpose of having private members in an object is to ensure the object itself can have some parts that it has absolute control of internally and can rely on those parts for certain behaviours. It is not to ensure privacy of the members since there are ways for them to be accessed in all languages (even if PHP makes it really easy).

You can make your own function which only exposes public properties if you want to:

```
function toAccessibleElementArray($object) {
    if (!is_object($object)) { return []; } //or other sensible default?
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
    $array = [];
    foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $property) {
        if ($property->isPublic()) {
             $array[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($object);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: If anyone uses this, make sure to do an is_object on $object before running this. Because get_class(null) will return the current class, which will give REALLY strange results for this method :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a documented behaviour:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.4

```
<?php
class A
{
   private $x=100;
   private $y=200;

}
$a=new A();

$m = function(){
    return [$this->x, $this->y];
};

[$x ,$y] = $m->call($a);

echo $x.','.$y;
```

You're not accessing private members there

```
<?php
class A
{
   private $x=100;
   private $y=200;
   private function __construct(){}
   public function setX(){
       $this->x =100;
   }
   public function setY(){
       $this->y =200;
   }
}
$a=new A();

$m = function(){
    return [$this->x, $this->y];
};
[$x ,$y] = $m->call($a);
echo $x.','.$y;
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to private A::__construct() from invalid context in
```